# Error installing Telerik Appbuilder CLI on Windows

Tags: telerik, npm, command-line-interface, telerik-appbuilder, telerik-platform

I am trying to install the `telerik appbuilder` CLI to my windows machine. the first error i was getting was cl.exe could not be found. i solved this by modifying  my install of visual studio community 2015 to include C++ and now i am getting alot more red in the cmd prompt window. i am trying to install the appbuilder using

```
npm install -g appbuilder
```

and here is a screenshot of the cmd window

[image: errors]

am i missing some dependencies?
the guide on how to set this up a is only the install line and after spending some time searching around. im not finding any others having problems setting appbuilder up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you check your version of node.js? At the moment of writing, AppBuilder CLI works with node.js 0.10.x and 0.12.x. Support for node.js 4.2.1 will be available in the 2.14 release, which is currently scheduled for releasing at the beginning of November 2015. Note that due to bug in V8 which crashes node, node 4.0.x will never be supported.

The reason for these messages is that AppBuilder CLI has dependencies written in C++. To build them, you need to satisfy all requirements for building c++ node modules, i.e. install Visual Studio, Python 2.7, node-gyp and configure them to be available on the command line. More information is available here: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp . Until our official support for node 4.2.1 is out, you may try this approach. Or, if possible, switch to node 0.12